# Any even is the sume of two primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-explanation

How can you prove or disprove that any even number is the sum of two primes?

Comment: Well, it's false as, 2 isn't.

Comment: If I knew that, I would be [famous](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture).

Comment: That's an unsolved conjecture, called the Goldbach's conjecture.  Hard problem, but there has actually been some progress on it over the last few decades.

Comment: "Any" is a word that is over-used by English-speaking mathematicians.  "Prove that any even number is purple" can reasonably be construed as "Pick any even number -- it doesn't matter which one -- and prove that it's purple." In effect that means _some_ even number -- at least one.  But "Any even number is purple.", however, means any even number -- no matter which one -- is purple, so "any" means _every_ rather than _some_. But if you precede that sentence with "prove that$\ldots$", then it become ambiguous in the way described above.  Simply saying "every" removes all ambiguity.

Answer (score 3):

You can disprove that any even is a sum of two primes by finding a counter-example.  So $n=2$ disproves it.  But if you exclude $n=2$ then it nobody has found another counter-example.  This is the famous Goldbach conjecture (google it).  To prove it you'd need to come up with a logical argument that reduces the result to previously known facts or axioms.